# Two StatsModels modules have totally different 'end-runs'

Tags: statsmodels

I'm running StatsModels to estimate parameters of a multiple regression model, using county-level data for 3085 counties.  When I use `statsmodels.formula.api`, and drop a few rows from the data, I get desired results. All seems well enough.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
%matplotlib inline
from statsmodels.compat import lzip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
eg=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/user/anaconda3/une_edu_pipc_06.csv')
pd.options.display.precision = 3
plt.rc("figure", figsize=(16,8))
plt.rc("font", size=14)
sm_col = eg["lt_hsd_17"] + eg["hsd_17"]
eg["ut_hsd_17"] = sm_col
sm_col2 = eg["sm_col_17"] + eg["col_17"]
eg["bnd_hsd_17"] = sm_col2
eg["d_09"]= eg["Rate_09"]-eg["Rate_06"]
eg["d_10"]= eg["Rate_10"]-eg["Rate_06"]
inc_2=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]
res = sm.ols(formula = "Rate_18 ~ p_c_inc_18  + ut_hsd_17 + d_10 + inc_2", 
                 data=eg, missing='drop').fit()
print(res.summary()).
```

(BTW, `eg["p_c_inc_18"]`is per-capita income, and `inc_2` is `p_c_inc_18` squarred).
But when I wish to use `import statsmodels.api as sm`as the module, everything else staying pretty much the same, and run the following code after all appropriate preliminaries,

```
inc_2=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]
X = eg[["p_c_inc_18","ut_hsd_17","d_10","inc_2"]]
y = eg["Rate_18"]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
res = mod.fit()   
print(res.summary())
```

then things fall apart, and the Python interpreter throws an error, as follows:

```
[......]
KeyError: "['inc_2'] not in index"
```

BTW, the only difference between the two 'runs' is that 15 rows are dropped during the first, successful, model run, while I don't as yet know how to drop missing rows from the second model formulation. Could that difference be responsible for why the second run fails? (I chose to omit large parts of the error message, to reduce clutter.)

Comment: check where the exception occurs. In general, don't drop the location information from a tracepack. I guess this is in the pandas data preparation and unrelated to OLS. You didn't add "inc_2" to your dataframe.

Comment: @Josef Thank you for the guidance. When `statsmodels.formula.api` had been used, `inc_2` was not included in the dataframe.  And yet OLS worked fine.  I am revising my question and  uploading afresh, including the full tracepack.

Comment: AFAIR, the patsy formula handling can also take things from the outer scope instead of just the dataframe. This was added as a similar feature to R. But the behavior of OLS is irrelevant for your KeyError in the second case.

Comment: eg["inc_2"]=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]
X = eg[["p_c_inc_18","ut_hsd_17","d_10","inc_2"]]
y = eg["Rate_18"]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
res = mod.fit()   
print(res.summary())

Comment: @Kevin Thank you.  I have run model after taking in you comment, as follows. 
`eg["inc_2"]=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]`
`X = eg[["p_c_inc_18","ut_hsd_17","d_10","inc_2"]]`
`y = eg["Rate_18"]`
`X = sm.add_constant(X)`
`mod = sm.OLS(y, X)`
`res = mod.fit()`   
`print(res.summary())`.  Error persists as follows: `MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans`.  The same model formulation produces intuitive results when I run it under statsmodels.formula.api.  BTW, how am I to invoke the `dropna` feature inside the statsmodels ols function mode: may be I should try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `inc_2` in your `DataFrame`.

```
inc_2=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]
```

should be

```
eg["inc_2"] = eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]
```